# Xcode Bots running UITesting on multiple iOS projects from a single Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I have setup an xcode project bot on an Xcode Server instance.  The bot runs all the UITesting test cases for that xcode project.  As part of our Continuous Integration strategy, I now want to run UITesting test cases from multiple xcode projects on the Xcode Server (similar to how you can on Jenkins) but cannot see a way how.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Was going to delete question, but since it was upvoted once, here is the answer in case anyone else needs it:

Bots for multiple xcode projects can be accessed from the 'Show the Report Navigator' tab (on the left hand navigation window in xcode).  So now I can open bots created in different xcode projects, but opening any one of those projects on the Xcode Server and viewing them all side by side.